# How do I use SWIG to return specific exceptions based on C function return type?

Tags: python, c, swig

Here are examples of functions in my C API:

```
int do_something(struct object *with_this)
struct object *get_something(struct object *from_this)
```

`do_something` will return `0` for success or `-1` and set `errno` for failure. `get_something` will return a valid pointer on success or `NULL` and set `errno` for failure.

I'm using to SWIG 2.0 to generate python bindings. For the `do_something` binding I'd like it to return an exception based on `errno` if it fails and return the Python `None` object if it succeeds. For the `get_something` binding I'd like it to return an exception based on `errno` if it fails and the opaque object if it succeeds.

The question is how do I get SWIG to do all of this magic for me?

Currently I'm using SWIG 2.0.

I can use `%exception` and define different exceptions per symbol, but I'd like it to be based on return type. I'll have a lot of the API functions and I don't want to list them out. So I can do this for each symbol:

```
%exception do_something {
    $action
    if (result < 0) {
        return PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_RuntimeError);
    }
}

%exception get_something {
    $action
    if (result == NULL) {
        return PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_RuntimeError);
    }
}
```

It would be a lot better if I could do something like this (like you can do with `%typemap`):

```
%exception int {
    $action
    if (result < 0) {
        return PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_RuntimeError);
    }
}

%exception struct object * {
    $action
    if (result == NULL) {
        return PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_RuntimeError);
    }
}
```

Can I do something like this? If I had something like this, then that would take care of the exceptions. And I believe my `get_something` binding would be perfect.

My `do_something` binding would still need something like this to get it to return the Python None object if I use `%typemap`:

```
%typemap(out) int {
    $result = Py_BuildValue("");
}
```

Does the magic I'm looking for exist or am I going about this all wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Pretty sure `%exception` is a red-herring for your use case and you want to do it all inside either `%typemap(out)` or even `%pythoncode` instead. I'll try and remember to write up a proper answer for you if nobody beats me to it.

Comment: Thanks Flexo. I've tried `typemap(out)` and the problem with that is I have to re-implement the type handling, which I don't want to do for the `get_something` case. For the `get_something` case I just want to handle the exception but still process the type as it were.

Comment: I see what you're concerned about, I'll have a think about it and show a few solutions then.

Comment: Random comment: are you trying to emulate OO behaviour with this series of functions with an implicit `this` parameter as the first argument on all of them? There's probably something neater you could do in your Python interface to save Python developers even caring that C isn't really OO if you wanted. (But that would be another question)

Comment: @Flexo Not exactly. My application here is that I have a C API that uses objects underneath. The important part is that I want to present the C API with an almost as-is usage to Python. Python will use [PyCapsule](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/capsule.html)s to pass this opaque object back and forth between the C API and Python layers. All functions will be [mutator/accessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) methods to maintain the opaqueness. So I want this as-is-ness with the ability to use the [EAFP](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper) principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help answer this question I took your functions and created the following test.h file that included enough real code to actually illustrate the problem:

```c
struct object { int bar; };

static int do_something(struct object *with_this) { 
  errno = EACCES;
  return -1; 
}

static struct object *get_something(struct object *from_this) {
  errno = EAGAIN;
  return NULL;
}
```

I'm fairly sure that `%typemap(out)` is the place to write this code in, not `%exception`, because the behaviour you want is determined by the return type, not the name of the function called. The fact that you also care about the value of the return further backs this up. You can to some degree avoid repetition using `$typemap` to reference other typemaps within yours.

So I wrote a little SWIG interface to illustrate this:

```c
%module test

%{
#include <errno.h>
#include "test.h"
%}

%typemap(out) int do_something %{
  if ($1 < 0) {
    PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_RuntimeError);
    SWIG_fail;    
  }
  $result = Py_None; // Return only controls exception
  Py_INCREF($result);
%}

%typemap(out) struct object *get_something %{
  if (!$1) {
    PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_RuntimeError);
    SWIG_fail; 
  }

  // Return passed through unless NULL
  $typemap(out,$1_ltype);
%}

%include "test.h"
```

Which worked when tested:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> test.do_something(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: (13, 'Permission denied')
>>> test.get_something(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: (11, 'Resource temporarily unavailable')
>>>
```

This only worked though because I explicitly named `do_something` when matching the typemap, so the fallback without the named function is fine. If you just try to remove that restriction you'll get an error about recursive typemaps. You can work around that using `%apply`, e.g.

```c
%typemap(out) struct object * MY_NULL_OR_ERRNO %{
  if (!$1) {
    PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_RuntimeError);
    SWIG_fail;
  }

  $typemap(out,$1_ltype);
%}

%apply struct object * MY_NULL_OR_ERRNO { struct object *get_something, struct object *some_other_function };
```

If that's too painful you can of course just write the typemap by hand:

```c
%typemap(out) struct object * %{
  if (!$1) {
    PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_RuntimeError);
    SWIG_fail;
  }

  $result = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr($1), $1_descriptor, $owner);
%}
```

Which seems the simplest option if you really want that *everywhere* a `struct object*` gets returned.

There are other possible solutions using `%pythoncode` or `%pythonappend`, but neither of them are really improvements over the above in my view.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Your last "typemap by hand" is what I like the best. I'm glad there's a way to get all that information through the automatic variables. Thanks for providing the alternatives as well; they will most definitely come in handy. Amazing answer!